# How to set executing Jar File Icon while exporting from eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I just want to export my java classes to jar file with **customize icon** from **eclipse**. 
I don't want that coffee mug symbol, You have any idea how to change default coffee mug icon of Jar file on executable **.jar** ? please help me on this..

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot change the icon of the resulting `.jar` file, since the icon of the linked application will be chosen from the linked executable (it's the same like with document files - they don't have their own icons saved in them as well, it just shows the icon of the executable of the office suite the document will be opened with) - In this case, this is `javaw.exe` (I assume you are talking about Windows).

---

A different approach is to choose something like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) - you are able to wrap your runnable jar file in a `.exe` file. You can then also customize the icon of this executable. The executable itself does not add much overhead in size: Only [around 33 kilobytes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=32982+bytes+in+kilobytes) (+the size if your `.ico` file) are added on top.